# MaxDropDownItems property behavior in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.maxdropdownitems(v=vs.110).aspx), `MaxDropDownItems` is used to get or set the maximum number of items to be shown in the drop-down portion of the ComboBox.

But this property has no effect until I set `IntegralHeight = false` and `DropDownHeight = 106` (Default value) together. This behavior is not documented any where in MSDN. If I change the `DropDownHeight` value other than the default value (106), `MaxDropDownItems` property has no use.

Is this correct or is there any fault in my usage/understanding?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to set `IntegralHeight = false` for the `MaxDropDownItems` to take effect.

Leave the `DropDownHeight` at the default value.